# Approximate the probability that the total service time of $100$ passengers is less than $15$ minutes.

Tags: probability

At airports, the service time (checking passport and ticket) of a passenger at the gate has an exponential distribution with mean $10$ seconds. Assume that service times of different passengers are independent random variables. 
Approximate the probability that the total service time of $100$ passengers is less than $15$ minutes.

From the Expectation (mean) I can compute that $E[X_1,...,X_{100}]=100*E[X]=100*10=1000$ so  $\lambda=0.001$, so I know that $P(x<k)=1-e^{-\lambda k}$ where $k=15$ and and $\lambda=0..01$, so my result is 0.014 but it should be 0.1587, where I'm wrong?

Comment: The basic error is that the sum of exponential variables is not another exponential variable.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: What @DavidK means is that if $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables with exponential distribution, you can't just conclude that $X+Y$ has an exponential distribution too. You're looking for the total service time. That's $X_1 + \cdots + X_{100}$ which is a sum of random variables with exponential distribution.

Comment: You computed the correct expected value, which is $1000$ seconds, but then you computed $P(x<k)$ as if you were dealing with an exponential distribution with mean $1000.$ It's like saying I can predict the total service time by measuring the time for the first passenger and then multiplying by $100.$ That would be an incorrect method, and you can see right away that it's incorrect if you look at the variance.

Comment: @DavidK oh yes, you are right, but then which method should I use?

Comment: Technically it's a gamma or Erlang distribution, but since you have so many iid variables it's reasonable to approximate it with a normal distribution as hinted in the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Since your random variables are i.i.d, use the [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem).

**Edit:**
You want to approximate the probability of the total service time of $100$ passengers. Assuming that $X_i$ is the service time for the $i$-th passenger, you want to approximate $S= X_1+\cdots+X_{100}$. As David mentioned in the comments, the distribution of $S$ is not known to us because the sum of two random variables whose distributions are exponential does not necessarily have an exponential distribution. But since $100$ is a relatively large number (any number bigger than $10$ is usually good enough for approximation by the CLT), we can say that $S$ has approximately the same distribution as the normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(n\mu,n\sigma^2)$ where $\mu$ is the mean and $\sigma^2$ is the variance of our original distribution and $n=100$ in our case.

For an exponential distribution with the rate $\lambda$, i.e. $P(X \leq t) = \lambda \exp(-\lambda t)$, the mean is given by $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ and the variance is given by $\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$. So, we have to determine what $\lambda$ is. The question says that the mean is $10$ seconds. So, $1/\lambda=10 \implies \lambda = 0.1$. This tells us that the variance is $100$ seconds. So, now you know that $S \sim \mathcal{N}(100\times 10, 100\times 100)$ approximately. To get the final answer, we have to convert $15$ minutes to seconds because we are measuring time in seconds. Therefore, we have:

$$P(S \leq 15\times 60) = P(\frac{S-1000}{100} \leq \frac{900-1000}{100})=P(Z < -1)=0.1587$$

where $Z=\frac{S-1000}{100}$ and $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

Comment: $P(Z<15)=P(Z<\frac{15/100-0.1}{\frac{\sqrt{0.01}}{\sqrt{100}}})=P(Z<5)$ right?

Comment: Well, have you calculated the mean and the standard deviation of your exponential distribution already? If yes, what are they?

Comment: Should not be $E[X_{100}]=100*E[X]$, $Var(X_{100})=100*Var(X)$?

Comment: Well, since you know that your distribution is exponential, you just need to determine $\lambda$ in $p(x \leq t)=\lambda \exp(-\lambda t)$. You know that the mean is $10$ seconds. So, $1/\lambda = 10$ and $\lambda = 0.1$. And the variance is equal to $0.01$ because for an exponential distribution, the variance is $1/\lambda^2$. Do you agree? Now, what can you conclude from the CLT?

Comment: Yes I agree for the expectation and variance, but the probability is not: $P(x<t)=1-e^{-\lambda t}$? And how can I related this with the CLT?

Comment: @MarkJacon  I added more information. Is it clear now? Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Oh now it's clear the reson but I still have some problem in the calculations, so $P(Z<15)=P(Z<\frac{15-100*0.1}{\sqrt{100*0.01}})=P(Z<5)=0.99$ (from the table) but it should be 0.15, where I'm wrong?

Comment: @MarkJacon  Did you read the last sentence which I added later? :P Don't forget to convert $15$ minutes to seconds. xD

Comment: oh sorry, now yes :) but if I multiply 15*60 and leave everything as it is above I have P(Z<890)

Comment: @MarkJacon  Yes, it's because the mean is $10$ seconds and the variance is $100$ seconds. We know that $\lambda$ is $0.1$ but the mean is $1/\lambda$ and the variance is $1/\lambda^2$. At the end, you should get $P(Z < -1) = 0.1587$

Comment: Is not what I wrote? $\mu=0.1$ and $\sigma =\sqrt{0.01}$?

Comment: @MarkJacon  Nope. The question says the mean is $10$ seconds. So, $\lambda$ is equal to $0.1$ and variance is $1/\lambda^2 = 100$ seconds. Don't forget that $\mu = 1/\lambda$.

Comment: @stessedout, sorry but I can't figured out where is the error, can you please write it in the answer? Thanks, and sorry again :)

Comment: @MarkJacon  I edited my answer again.

Comment: Now it's clear, thanks a lot!

Comment: @MarkJacon  You're welcome